# Docker swarm on 'dind' images and networking problems

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am trying to create a local swarm environment based on 'dind' images. Below are the steps for environment recreation:

```
docker network create --attachable --subnet 10.0.0.0/16 tools_network

docker run -d --privileged --name swarm-manager-1 --hostname swarm-manager-1 --network tools_network --ip 10.0.0.3 -p 42421:2375 docker:17.03.1-dind

docker --host localhost:42421 swarm init --advertise-addr 10.0.0.3

docker run -d --privileged --name swarm-worker-1 --hostname swarm-worker-1 --network tools_network --ip 10.0.0.4 -p 42423:2375 docker:17.03.1-dind

docker --host localhost:42423 swarm join --token <swarm-token> 10.0.0.3:2377
```

After that I add an nginx-based proxy:

```
docker run -d --name swarm-proxy --network tools_network -v $(pwd)/temp-proxy:/etc/nginx:ro -p 80:80 nginx:stable-alpine
```

with the following contents of nginx.conf in the 'temp-proxy' folder:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    upstream swarm {
        server 10.0.0.3;
        server 10.0.0.4;

    }

    server {
        listen          80 default_server;
        listen          [::]:80 default_server;

        location / {
            proxy_pass      http://swarm;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
}
```

The service I use for testing purposes is launched by:

```
docker --host localhost:42421 service create --name test-web --publish 80:80 yeasy/simple-web
```

What I expect at this stage, based on the [mesh networking documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/) is that `curl localhost` will return the result from the deployed service. However, I get a 502 Bad Gateway response, with the following log messages from the proxy:

```
[error] 7#7: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.0.4:80/", host: "localhost"
[error] 7#7: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.0.3:80/", host: "localhost"
10.0.0.1 - -  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 173 "-" "curl/7.47.0"
```

Same result (connection refused) for curling from a docker container deployed to the `tools_network`.

Running `netstat -l` from inside one of the swarm nodes shows that they don't listen on port 80:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:38943        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::2375                 :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::2377                 :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::7946                 :::*                    LISTEN      
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:35094        0.0.0.0:*                           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4789            0.0.0.0:*                           
udp        0      0 :::7946                 :::*
```

### The questions are:

1. Is there something wrong with my configuration? What is it?
2. If not, what steps should I take to get to the problem's root?

Comment: Can you ping `10.0.0.1` from nginx host?

Comment: @harshavmb what do you mean by 'nginx host'? The docker host for the 1st level containers? It shouldn't matter, I believe, because I access the proxy service using the locally mapped ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of investigations I found the problem looking at [this](https://github.com/dweomer/docker-swarm-local/blob/master/docker-compose.yml).
 Docker inside dind images couldn't initialize properly due to absent modules and I actually saw the errors in the container logs (`docker logs swarm-manager-1`) but didn't pay attention to them.

So the solution for me was launching the swarm nodes like this:

```
docker run -d --privileged --name swarm-manager-1 --hostname swarm-manager-1 --network tools_network --ip 10.0.0.3 -p 42421:2375 -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules:ro docker:17.03.1-dind
```

where the `/lib/modules` mapping is the piece that was absent.